# Chessboard GUI 2D View

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, chess, tkinter-canvas

I would like to create a 2D chessboard representation for the GUI of my chess game with Tkinter. I programmed [this code](http://pastebin.com/11gjXkrx) but it doesn't display the chessboard, it just displays the grey background. There is no indentation problem. What's the problem, and how can I fix it?

This is the error I get when I run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Chess\GAME\gui.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Chess\GAME\gui.py", line 29, in main
    gui = GUI(root)
  File "D:\Chess\GAME\gui.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.draw_board()
AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute 'draw_board'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there *is* an indentation problem.  You've made **draw_board** a sub-function of **__init__**, rather than a class method.  Pull it left to the same level as **__init__** so it can be a property of your object **GUI**.